# Java XML parser duplicating elements on list

Tags: java, android, xml, sax, tmx

I have a SAX2 XML parser and I want to perform specific actions.

1. Add an object to `tileFrames` list when frame element starts (as many times as frame in each animation element),
2. Add String `currentTileID` with this `tileFrames` list when animation element ends.
3. Clear a `tileFrames` list when animation starts so that the `tileAnimations` list receive its elements and without ellements dedcated for another animation element.

I want this scenario to perfomr as long as there are no more animation tags in my xml file.

Now I receive list of objects with correct `currentTileID` but with the same elements like it was the last animation iteration.

Here is what I get when I log:

```
2023-04-16 14:07:30.538 25714-25714/abc.def.ghi D/tile_animations: TileAnimation{localGID=21, tileFrames=[TileFrame{tileId=42, duration=500}, TileFrame{tileId=43, duration=500}]}
2023-04-16 14:07:30.538 25714-25714/abc.def.ghi D/tile_animations: TileAnimation{localGID=22, tileFrames=[TileFrame{tileId=42, duration=500}, TileFrame{tileId=43, duration=500}]}
2023-04-16 14:07:30.538 25714-25714/abc.def.ghi D/tile_animations: TileAnimation{localGID=43, tileFrames=[TileFrame{tileId=42, duration=500}, TileFrame{tileId=43, duration=500}]}
(...)
```

Here is the key code (if I cut off too much code I will attach more, I just wanted to simplify things):

TmxHandler.java

```
@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("animation")) {
        tileFrames.clear();

    } else if (localName.equals("frame")) {
        tileFrames.add(new TileFrame(Long.parseLong(atts.getValue("tileid")), Long.parseLong(atts.getValue("duration"))));

    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) {
     if (localName.equals("animation")) {
        currentTileSet.tileAnimations.add(new TileAnimation(Long.parseLong(currentTileID), tileFrames));


    } else if (localName.equals("frame")) {

    } 
}
```

TileAnimation.java

```
public class TileAnimation {

private long localGID;
private List<TileFrame> tileFrames;

public long getLocalGID() {
    return localGID;
}

public void setLocalGID(long localGID) {
    this.localGID = localGID;
}

public List<TileFrame> getTileFrames() {
    return tileFrames;
}

public void setTileFrames(List<TileFrame> tileFrames) {
    this.tileFrames = tileFrames;
}

public TileAnimation(long localGID, List<TileFrame> tileFrames) {
    this.localGID = localGID;
    this.tileFrames = tileFrames;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TileAnimation{" +
            "localGID=" + localGID +
            ", tileFrames=" + tileFrames +
            '}';
}
```

}

And here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.10" tiledversion="1.10.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="8" height="12" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" infinite="0" nextlayerid="11" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="RPG Nature Tileset" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="180" columns="20">
  <image source="NatureTileset.png" width="641" height="288"/>
  <tile id="21">
   <animation>
    <frame tileid="21" duration="1000"/>
    <frame tileid="1" duration="1000"/>
    <frame tileid="20" duration="1000"/>
   </animation>
  </tile>
  <tile id="22">
   <animation>
    <frame tileid="22" duration="100"/>
    <frame tileid="2" duration="100"/>
   </animation>
  </tile>
  <tile id="43">
   <animation>
    <frame tileid="42" duration="500"/>
    <frame tileid="43" duration="500"/>
   </animation>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="181" name="32x32_map_tile v3.1 [MARGINLESS]" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="667" columns="23">
  <image source="32x32_map_tile v3.1 [MARGINLESS].png" width="736" height="928"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer id="1" name="grass" width="8" height="12">
  <data encoding="csv">
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,142,142,142,142,41,41,
41,41,142,41,142,41,41,41,
41,41,41,142,142,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="9" name="anim1" width="8" height="12">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,44,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="10" name="anim2" width="8" height="12">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

If you need something more just ask.

Answer (score 0):

SCREEN
ColorDepth:
24
PixelDepth:
24
Height:
820
Width:
360
AvailHeight:
820
AvailWidth:
360
AvailTop:
0
AvailLeft:
0
Window size:
360x3598 (360x820)
PLUGINS
Plugins missing
EXTENDED
WebGL:
076f790265bc8796
Canvas:
-151063313
Audio:
8fb5fa54c9d5e0c0
Fonts:
202a809ae5defaa7
Client Rects:
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d
TIME
Zone:
Africa/Lagos
Local:
Sat Apr 15 2023 00:44:44 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
System:
Sun Apr 16 2023 06:08:19 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
IP
WEBRTC
104.28.155.240
JAVASCRIPT
Enabled
FLASH
Disabled
ACTIVEX
Disabled
JAVA
Disabled
COOKIESloxked209.85.255.255
Enabled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).